# Rounding a double value With Exponent

Tags: c#, double, rounding, exponent

I have a double value 0.000034 for example and I want a double value 3.40E-5 (please note that the second value required is also a double value and not string). All the results I have found so far convert the value to the string format which is not intended. I have list of doubles for my chart program.

[Image of the resulted Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QQwy.png)

I have added the image. Here the yellow highlighed row shows 0 (percentage) but infact it is a very very small number that I want to display here. But it is just displayed as 0 which was not intended.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `3.40E-5` is purely a string representation of a `double`.

Comment: what do want to do with your values in the chart?

Comment: Although I did not vote down, But your post is simply missing a "question"

Comment: Is it a problem you have in your debugger showing the values???

Answer (score 3):

0.000034 and 3.40e-5  are just 2 different ways to declare same variable with same value, it has nothing to do with rounding. You will see "E" only when you represent value as string. So if you declare 2 variables like below, they will have identical value;

```
double value1 = 0.000034;
double value2 = 3.40e-5;
```

Comment: And indeed you can do this and it will not fail: `Debug.Assert(0.000034 == 3.40e-5);`

Comment: "You will see "E" only when you represent value as string. " is not correct statement, I see it also if I round the double to more decimal places than 2.

Comment: Where do you see it? Visual studio debugger also shows you value in string representation. Real value is stored in memory the way like described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format   If you write something like (3.40e-5).ToString("F15"), you'll get 15 fractional numbers in double variable